# Optimization of complex multi-model query in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

I need an easy control of what products shown on which site, and since there are lots of products, I would also like to set product sites via category, producer and tags. So I show a product on a site if the product OR (its category AND its producer AND one of its tags) are linked to the site. The code I ended up with is the following (simplified):

```
from django.db.models import Model, ManyToManyField, ForeignKey, BooleanField

class Site(Model):
    enabled = BooleanField()

class Producer(Model):
    sites = ManyToManyField(Site)

class Category(Model):
    sites = ManyToManyField(Site)

class Tag(Model):
    sites = ManyToManyField(Site)

class Product(Model):
    producer = ForeignKey(Producer)
    category = ForeignKey(Category)
    tags     = ManyToManyField(Tag)
    sites    = ManyToManyField(Site)

    def get_site_ids(self):
        if self.sites.exists():
            return list(self.sites.values_list('id', flat=True))
        else:
            p = list(self.producer.sites.values_list('id', flat=True))
            c = list(self.category.sites.values_list('id', flat=True))
            t = sum([list(tag.sites.values_list('id', flat=True)) for tag in self.tags.all()], [])
            ids = set.intersection(set(p), set(c), set(t))
            return ids
```

My question is how can I optimize `get_sites` method? Is it possible to join some of the queries?

---

Update: I am interested just in site ids which will be indexed and stored by search engine.

Answer (score 1):

You should try and do everything you want to do on the database level if possible. Something like this should get you started.

```
from django.db.models import Sum
self.objects.select_related("producer__sites",
                            "category__sites",
                            "tags__sites",
                            "sites").annotate(tag_count=Sum("tags__sites__id"))
```

`select_related` returns the `Product` model with the producer, category, tags and sites references filled. This also includes the `sites` reference in producer, category and tags. This make Django do less queries to the database.

`annotate` adds an attribute to the returned `Model` instance named `tag_count` that has the Sum of tags_*sites*_id in it.

The Django [QuerySet Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) might be a good help because I don't know the exact nature of what you want to have returned.

Comment: Thanks! I need just site ids.

Comment: Unfortunately, Sum aggregator does not help me here, since I need to collect site ids. I need to run more queries (e.g. with `prefetch_related` mentioned by @pram).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can reduce the number of queries in Django using `select_related` and/or `prefetch_related`.

However, the `select_related` only works for foreign key and one-on-one relationships. Since you have ManyToMany in your Product model, you should use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to reduce your queries in Product.get_sites().